# Prevent roles from being inherited by a managed identity

Tags: azure, roles, identity-management

I want to create a managed identity with minimal rights configuration, unfortunately BuiltInRoles like "Log Analytics Contributor" are assigned automatically when creating a new managed identity.

I can neither edit nor delete these roles.

How do I create an "empty" managed identity or prevent roles from being inherited by a managed identity?

**What I have tried**

I searched via Google and read various Microsoft documentation and found this information:

> "If you see a message that inherited role assignments cannot be removed, you are trying to remove a role assignment at a child scope. You should open Access control (IAM) at the scope where the role was assigned and try again."

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-remove

I then checked the Access Control in the Subscription as well as in the Resource Group. There, the roles can also not be removed or edited. There are also significantly more rights assigned than in the managed identity. Even if I create a completely new resource group for the managed identity, predefined rights are assigned there again. I cannot determine what the "parent scope" is.

When I check "role assignments" I see "Subscription (Inherited)", but I checked the subscription level.

**Expected result**

I expect / hope to find a solution to create an empty managed identity or prevent inheritance of rights.

Comment: Have you had a look at User Assigned Managed Identity instead of system-assigned ? You would get the full freedom you are looking for : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identity-best-practice-recommendations#choosing-system-or-user-assigned-managed-identities

Comment: I think so, yes. When I add a new managed identity the title is: "Create User Assigned Managed Identity". This is also the way I created the previous managed identities.